# How to select excel cells range only alphabet followed?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing vba script which select cells range in excel sheet but it select in this format $G$1:$K$1 but i need only this format $G:$K eliminate number while selecting or any other method to eliminate number followed by $.

```
Sub vloos()

Dim rnge As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim user As String
Dim file As String
file = "E:\output4.xls"
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs file
    Set nb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
    Set ns = nb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'get workbook path
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xls", Title:="Please select a file")


    'set our workbook and open it
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    'set our worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'set the range for vlookup

On Error GoTo En
    Set rnge = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range to format:", Title:="Format Range", Type:=8)

    Set Rng = ws.Range(rnge.Address)

    MsgBox Rng.Address
En:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `EntireColumn` property of the `Range` object to get the columns

```
On Error GoTo En
    Set rnge = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range to format:", Title:="Format Range", Type:=8)

    Set Rng = rnge.EntireColumn

    MsgBox Rng.Address
```

Comment: I am getting no output when i use rnge.EntireColumn program end from that line.

Comment: I am getting error "Application defined or object defined error".

Comment: @Kathirvtv when I run `Debug.Print Range("$A$3:$C$20").EntireColumn.Address` in the Immediate Window then it prints `$A:$C`. Make sure the syntax of the entered range expression is correct

Comment: @xmojmr I am also getting same when run  "Range("$A$3:$C$20").EntireColumn.Address" this line, but when change instead of this $A$3:$C$20 into variable only getting problem and i also tried this format Rng = ws.Range("rnge.EntireColumn.Address"), Rng = ws.Range("rnge.EntireColumn"), Debug.Print Rng = ws.Range("rnge").EntireColumn.Address but no output.

Comment: @Kathirvtv you can use `Set Rng = ws.Range(rnge.EntireColumn.Address)` (no double quotes) but it would be the same as `Set Rng = rnge.EntireColumn` assuming that `ws` points to the `ActiveSheet`. Or you can use something like `Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(rnge.EntireColumn.Address)` to open the range window in another sheet

Comment: @Kathirvtv, what is returned if you use `Debug.Print rnge.Address & ", " & rnge.Parent.Name` after the `Set rnge = Application.InputBox` line?